# How to handle a fussy baby?

Tags: newborn, crying

How do I handle my 6 weeks old baby who is always crying and needs to be held and walk while holding him. knowing that they are twins and I can't keep holding him since I have his brother to take care of him too. 
N.B.: This baby was born underweight (1380 g) and was kept in the NICU for about 18 days.

Comment: Both my girls (now 14mo twins) wanted to be carried all the time in the first months, it ended up VERY exhausting. Before my husband would leave for work, I would make sure I had water and snacks close by and then... sit on the couch with the nursing pillow (for twins) around me to let the girls be in contact with me. I would put them down when asleep. It's a phase, an exhausting one but it'll get better...

Comment: @Fanny H. how long will this phase last??

Comment: unfortunatly, as for most answers related to baby's phases... it'll depend on the kids. One of mine is now really independent while the other still wants to sit on my laps or be in my arms regularly, but they started doing much better when they could do tummy time and then be in a bouncing chairs. Right now, they are just fresh out of the womb and still need to feel their mom's warmth :)

Answer (score 4):

Can you wear him?  My preemie LOVED being worn, and it freed up my hands to do the other things that needed doing.  Try a Moby wrap or something similar; there are oodles of how-to videos online that show you how to properly tie is so he's safe and secure and able to breathe freely, and you get your hands back.

Comment: +1 for wearing. However DO NOT use your now freed hands to slice onions while wearing the baby... Especially if the poor creature's eyes are near the onion.

Comment: +1 for the Moby wrap which also includes specific instructions on how to wear twins so Zeina could, conceivably, wear both boys simultaneously!  Both my kids did well in our Moby.  Some kids don't like it so much and you might find that to be the case with your other twin, but it would probably help this one feel more secure and you less restricted!

Answer (score 2):

Even I have twins 11 mo old and one of them is somewhat underweight, tiny and very Fussy.
She loves crying and constantly pokes and loves troubling her Twin sister.
So I let her CRY.
It helps in removing pent up frustration and makes her Feel better.
I wait for 15 minutes to let her stop crying by herself and when she does stop, I pick her in my arms and give her lots of hugs and cuddles.

Comment: My fussy baby was also born underweight and he is small and tiny too.

Comment: My daughter Sneha is just 15 lbs at 11 months whereas her twin sister is double her weight.

Comment: This is a very good answer - effectively answers the question with what to do and why.